# Postfix Dovecot unix Error : missing '=' after attribute

Tags: postfix, ldap, dovecot

According to multiple documents like https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix/DovecotLDAP

One of the configuration lines is:

```
    dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=mail:mail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${user}
```

By putting the above in **/etc/postfix/main.cf** I get the following error:

> postmulti: fatal: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 69-70: missing '=' after attribute                                                                                         name: "dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe  flags=DRhu                                                                                         user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}

Am assuming this is a whitespace issue and the same issue has been reported multiple times, but no clear solution/reason is provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Ubuntu document](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix/DovecotLDAP) linked above, those lines must be placed in `master.cf` not `main.cf`

> Now to allow dovecot for delivery, add the following entry to **master.cf**
>
> > ```
> > dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
> >   flags=DRhu user=mail:mail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${user}
> > ```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I clearly overlooked that. Hopefully no one else will ever make this silly mistake again.